# Any way to concatenate two strings and remain the quotes(Python)?

Tags: python, string, concatenation, quotes, f-string

I wrote a function which includes a groupby aggregation. For example `df.groupby([column, 'columnA', 'columnB', 'columnE'....'columnZ'].sum()`, where `column` is the input variable. Since there are many groupby columns, I don't want to rewrite all of them for different aggregation-levels. For one output, I need to have column equal to one string, but for another output, I need to have two column strings (one more layer of aggregation-level).

I am trying to concatenate two strings for example, `'Category_col1'` and `'Category_col2'`.
If I simply add two strings using `'Category_col1' + ', Category_col2'`, it will return `'Category_col1, Category_col2'`

My desired output looks like this: `'Category_col1', 'Category_col2'`. An output of `"'Category_col1', 'Category_col2'"` would not work if I use that with other groupby aggregation columns. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: What type of object are you trying to make with `'apple', 'banana'`? If it's a string, that would be `"'apple', 'banana'"`. Is *that* what you want?

Comment: I wrote a function which includes a groupby aggregation. For example df.groupby([column, 'columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC'....'columnZ'].sum(). For one output, I need to have column equal to one string, but for another output, I need to have two column strings.

Comment: This is a string: `"'Category_col1', 'Category_col2'"`. This is a tuple `'Category_col1', 'Category_col2'`. Do you want a tuple of a string? Consider what happens here: `print('Category_col1', 'Category_col2')` vs `print("'Category_col1', 'Category_col2'")`

Comment: I guess I need a tuple then. I edited my question, hopefully it's clearer.

Comment: So a tuple is made simply with `some_tuple = 'Category_col1', 'Category_col2'`. Then `some_tuple[0]` is `'Category_col1'` and `len(some_tuple)`  is `2`.

Comment: But I don't think tuple works here either. For example, tuple = ('Category_col1', 'Category_col2'), when I use that as the column input, the aggregation would become like this: df.groupby([('Category_col1', 'Category_col2'), 'columnA', 'columnB', 'columnE'....'columnZ'].sum(), which doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```py
def my_concat(stringA, stringB):
    return f"'{stringA}',  '{stringB}'"

print(my_concat('apple','banana'))
```

prints the string `"'apple',  'banana'"`

EDIT:
For building them into a tuple

```py
def make_tuple(stringA, stringB):
    return stringA,  stringB
print(make_tuple('apple','banana'))
```

or just omit the function altogether

```py
print(('apple','banana'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made some clarifications to my questions. Please take a look

Comment: `'Category_col1', 'Category_col2'` is not a string. The string would have to look like `"'Category_col1', 'Category_col2'"`. Are you looking for a tuple?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should be tuple then.

Comment: then just make them into a tuple `print(('apple','banana'))`

Comment: But if I don't think tuple works here either. For example, tuple = ('Category_col1', 'Category_col2'), when I use that as the column input, the aggregation would became like this: df.groupby([('Category_col1', 'Category_col2'), 'columnA', 'columnB', 'columnE'....'columnZ'].sum(), which doesn't work.

Comment: then i'm still not sure I understand the desired result. What do you want the output to look like in this "df.groupby" context

Comment: For df1, I want to replace the input variable column with 'Category_col1' so that the script would be written as df.groupby(['Category_col1', 'columnA', 'columnB', 'columnE'....'columnZ'].sum(). For df2, I want to replace the input variable column with 'Category_col1', 'Category_col2' so that the script would be written as df.groupby(['Category_col1', 'Category_col2', 'columnA', 'columnB', 'columnE'....'columnZ'].sum()

Comment: This is not string concatenation or tuple building. It looks like you want to insert another string into the list which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So, do you think this is do-able?